# Fast writing: Memory-Mapped file versus BufferedWriter

Tags: java, file-io, io, real-time, nio

Has anyone benchmarked this? I want to write as fast as possible to disk, minimizing the latency of my write calls. I wonder if writing to a memory mapped buffer (through buffer.put()) is faster than just buffering the contents in the Java side and just flushing to the fileChannel once the buffer is full. That way I would be just making a system call (FileChannel.write) once the buffer gets full. I am not sure what happens when I write some bytes to the MappedByteBuffer, in other words, if a system call is done or not.

With the buffered approach, I would be able to write to the disk in chunks of 16,32 or 64k, which I believe is optimum. The drawback of buffering is that you must have a shutdown hook to flush the contents if the application crashes. And an extra layer of copying to the buffer instead of writing straight to the file channel. And if you tail the file you may not see what you want because the contents are buffered. I also have no clue what happens if you tail a memory mapped file.

Any experienced soul can help out here?

Comment: I haven't benchmarked this, so this is a comment, but from everything I've read memory mapped IO is _supposed_ to be much faster.

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to minimise latency, I have found writing to MemoryMappedFiles to be faster because it *avoids* the need to make a system call.  This assumes you don't need to force the data to disk and are happy for the OS to do this on a best effort basis.

The typical latency for writing to a MemoryMappedFile is the same as writing to memory, so i don't believe you will get faster.  As the file grows you need to perform an additional memory mapped regions and this can take 50 to 100 micro-seconds which is significant but should be rare enough that it doesn't matter.

Writing to IO via a system call takes in the order of 5 to 10 micro-seconds which is fast enough for more applications, but relatively much slower if it matters.

If you have a need to see the data as it is written with a low latency, I suggest you look at my library [Java Chronicle](https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Chronicle) which supports reading data with a typical latency of 100 ns from the time it is written.

Note: While memory mapped files can reduce latency of individual writes it doesn't increase the write throughput of your disk subsystem.  This means that if you have a slow disk sub-system, your memory will soon become exhausted (even if you have many GBs) and this will be the performance bottleneck regardless of which approach you take.

For example if you have SATA or fibre, you might have a limit of 500 MB/s which is easy to exceed in which case once you hit you memory limit, this will slow you down regardless of what you chose.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. My need is low latency but I don't care too much about throughput. It looks in theory that writing to a memory mapped file would be as fast as writing to another thread for asynch logging, or even faster because there is no need for synchronization, but in practice I have seen that async logging is way faster. Maybe because my [non-blocking queue](http://mentaqueue.soliveirajr.com) is ultra-fast but I feel I need to do more benchmarks on that matter. One thing I am doing is pausing for a number of ns before each log to lower the throughput. That made it much faster (~300ns).

Comment: I would be interested to see your results. I see less than 200 ns round trip from process A to process B back to process A and if you have found something faster than that I would like to know.

Comment: @TraderJoeChicago: Memory mapping must occasionally close the mapping, extend the file, and reopen the mapping, all synchronously.  A background thread avoids this.  I'd guess that's the difference.

Comment: @PeterLawrey "This assumes you don't need to force the data to disk and are happy for the OS to do this on a best effort basis." How can we do that?

Comment: @Abidi the OS does this by default. This will happen if you don't force the data to disk.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Probably deserves a new question: I've a 8 byte of memory mapped file, writer is writing, rewinding and waiting for consumer to consume (based on another MMF to maintain seq numbers),  tried over 100M messages, all written and read. Does OS gaurantee data "visibility" between two processes? This wouldn't have worked if two threads were sharing memory without a volatile/memory barrier.

Comment: @Abidi If you have 8 bytes in a MMF, you can write to it by offset (no need to rewind) and read from another process. However, you still need a memory barrier, which is provided by the CPU, the OS isn't involved. However, many OS calls end up having a full memory barrier as a side effect. The simplest way to add such memory barriers is to write any volatile field after your write to the MMF and a read to any volatile field before reading from the MMF. The JVM doesn't guarantee this will work, but it will happen to work on most CPUs.

Comment: @Abidi if you use the Chronicle Bytes library we have thread safe operations built in using `Unsafe`. The simplest example is here. http://blog.vanillajava.blog/2022/01/distributed-unique-time-stamp.html

Comment: @PeterLawrey Would file locking yield the same result in terms of ensuring data consistency/visibility between processes? I understand, performing file lock and unlock operations per message (4*100M times in my case) both by the consumer and producer may slow things down.

Comment: @Abidi Probably, though it would be around 100x slower. Have you considered using Chronicle Queue, which passes messages between processes via memory-mapped files? It handles this locking for you.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Created a producer to write 100M Longs to a file, a consumer to consume all of those longs (using volatile write and read). I had writer done in about 900ms and consumer in 500ms. I was surprised by this kind of performance, verified a few times that consumer is definitely reading every single Long and this IS the case. Does this sound right that consumer would read a single msg in 5 nanosecond or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: @Abidi That sounds about right if you write and then read the data sequentially. If you write to a tmpfs drive you can probably reduce the write time.

Comment: @PeterLawrey But latency to read/write to memory is much higher than 5-6 nanos (at least on my 2019 MBP), is this all happening in L1-L3 cache (via cache coherence protocol) between consumer and producer and memory is never accessed synchronously? Is it possible to see/profile when and how many calls to memory were made?

Comment: @abidi reading 100 m longs in 500 ms is an average of 5 ns per read. Can you clarify what you mean?